DBeaver + Firebird Execution plan has no costs / details
I want to use the Query-Execution-Plan from DBeaver for a Firebird 2.5.1, but there are always no details or costs listed. Is there something needed in the connection driver properties or somewhere else?


Firebird cannot show cost in plans. Detailed plan is available starting from version 3 so 2.5 cannot provide it anyway.

Thanks for that fast support @user13964273. If you want to answer, I will accept your post. Thanks!

Like user13964273 commented, this is available in Firebird 3 and above:

Firebird cannot show cost in plans. Detailed plan is available starting from version 3 so 2.5 cannot provide it anyway.

